# Append string to JSX

Tags: reactjs

In the below code sample, I need to add the string " : " only if the `twitter` props is set. What is the right way to do this?

```
let User = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        let twitter = (this.props.twitter) ? (this.renderTwitter(this.props.twitter)) : null;
        return (<div>{this.props.name} : {twitter}</div>)
    },
    renderTwitter: function(twitter) {
        return (<a href={'http://www.twitter.com/' + twitter} >Twitter</a>)
    }
})


let App = React.createClass( {
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>User List</h1>
                <User name="User 1" twitter="handle1"/>
                <User name="User 2"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Tried the following:

```
render: function() {
    let twitter = (this.props.twitter) ? " : " + (this.renderTwitter(this.props.twitter)) : null;
    return (<div>{this.props.name} : {twitter}</div>)
}
```

Tried this as well:

```
renderTwitter: function(twitter) {
    return (: <a href={'http://www.twitter.com/' + twitter} >Twitter</a>)
}
```

Comment: Just use an extra HTML tag as wrapper, See this fiddle. [https://jsfiddle.net/0baspe5t/](https://jsfiddle.net/0baspe5t/)

Comment: do you want to add ":" after the twitter link(anchor tag)

Comment: Sure, I'll add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your anchor tag with another tag.

```
return (
     <span>
        :&nbsp; 
        <a href={'http://www.twitter.com/' + twitter}>
           Twitter
        </a>
     </span>
)
```

Here, is the working fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0baspe5t/)

Benefit of doing this in a separate function is its re-usability. If you need to display twitter handle anywhere else, you can just call this function.

Answer (score 2):

What about this one:

```
const User = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    const { twitter } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
      {this.props.name}
      {twitter && (
        <span>
          :&nbsp; 
          <a href={`http://www.twitter.com/${twitter}`}>
            Twitter
          </a>
        </span>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

[demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/0baspe5t/3/)

We're getting `twitter` from props, and then we use

```
{twitter && (/*something to render*/)}
```

so it'll be rendered only if twitter is **truthy**

Comment: The best solution IMHO, it shows how to make this w/o polluting with other tags and combining JSX & text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    render: function() {
       return (
          <div>
              {this.props.name} : 
              {this.props.twitter?<span>:<a href={'http://www.twitter.com/' + twitter}>Twitter</a></span>:null}
          </div>
       )
    },
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but does this not throw a syntax error, since you're using the ternary operator wrong(using 2 colons)? How does the compiler know that you mean html when mentioning the first colon(right after the <span> tag)?

Comment: No, because the first colon is inside the span tag so it is treated as an element in the HTML of span tag. JSX identifies the body of HTML tags by the opening tag and closing tag and here the first colon lies before closing span tag to JSX considers it as in the body of span tag.If you want to be extra cautious you can place the complete tag in brackets e.g. {this.props.twitter?(<span>:<a href={'http://www.twitter.com/' + twitter}>Twitter</a></span>):null}

Comment: You should also think in terms of re-usability of the code. In your case, If I want to use the same functionality somewhere else, I can't use it. I'll need to copy-paste the same code. So it's always better to move common code to a separate function so that it can be reused.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Hardik Modha. Reusability completely depends on many times I require the exact same code component. If I have to be concerned about reusability then I would create a separate component for this purpose which will lead to ease of reusability and cleaner code as well.

Comment: Yes, You are right. It leads to cleaner and maintainable code. Here in op's case, there can be multiple users having twitter handle. So reusability of the code will come into picture.